# how to change grid store on some condition

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have one dynamic ExtJS grid.

```
items: {  
    xtype: 'grid',
    border: false,
    columnLines: true,
    scrollable: true,
    stripeRows: true,
    columns: changeColumns,
    store: store1 /// How to change store here
},
```

and store 1 is some thing like

```
store1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: Fields1,
    data: Data1
});
```

and store 1 is some thing like

```
store2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: Fields1,
    data: Data2
});
```

So I want to change my store on basis of some condition given below.
Now my condition is

```
if(headersXmlDoc.getAttribute("ST") == 1){
    Store1
}else if(headersXmlDoc.getAttribute("ST") == 2){
    Store2
}
```

Can any body tell me how to achive this.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the grid's [reconfigure](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#method-reconfigure) method.

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1pdi

Comment: Thanks for answer. Any working example for this will help me to understand.